# How to find substring in python from file name

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I am new to python and I want to get particular substring from the file path.

```
file_list = 'pdl-skills-data/pdl_raw_data/skills_pdl_data_<company_name>.csv'
```

example :

```
file_list = 'pdl-skills-data/pdl_raw_data/skills_pdl_data_Visa.csv'
```

I want to store value in a variable , so that I can use it in output file name

```
Company_Name=Visa

final_df.to_csv("original_df_with_clusters.csv")
timestamp = datetime.now().strftime('%Y%m%d%H%M')
result_path = 'pdl-skills-data/pdl_result_data/'
result = f'{result_path}original_df_with_clusters_{Company_Name}_{timestamp}.csv'
bucket.upload_file("original_df_with_clusters.csv", result)
```

Comment: Does skills_pdl_data stay the same in all your strings?

Comment: yes,  skills_pdl_data will be always there

Comment: In that case you may get the substring by ```initial_index = file_list.find('skills_pdl_data_')``` and it is give you the initial character index lets say that is 7. then you add the length of above substring skills_pdl_data_ which is 16. so ```last_index = initial_index+16``` which would be 23. so 23 is last index of substring skills_pdl_data_. so 24 will be the first index of your company. so then you would do: ```company_name = file_list[last_index+1:-4]```. -4 is to remove the ```.csv``` part. hence that will give you the company name.

Answer (score 0):

If the string always follows exactly the same structure, you could pull it out with a slice:

```py
company_name = file_list[45:-4]
```